# protobuf can't be serialized

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

---

hello eyeryone,

my protobuf version is 2.5.0, the generated header file just contains a `SerializeWithCachedSizes` method, I want to serialize my protobuf object to char array, and post the array by socket. in lots of tutorials refer to a method `SerializeToArray` method, I just need this method, but why my header file doesn't contains this method?
the first time to use protobuf, not familiar with that. if anyone can solve the problem, please show me the detail code.

**proto file as:**

```
package ddz.proto;

option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;
option java_package = "ddz.proto";
option java_outer_classname = "Login";

message LoginMessage {
    optional string userAccount = 1;
}
```

**and generated header file as:**

```
// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: hello.proto

#ifndef PROTOBUF_hello_2eproto__INCLUDED
#define PROTOBUF_hello_2eproto__INCLUDED

#include <string>

#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>

#if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 2005000
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
#error your headers.
#endif
#if 2005000 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif

#include <google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h>
#include <google/protobuf/message_lite.h>
#include <google/protobuf/repeated_field.h>
#include <google/protobuf/extension_set.h>
// @@protoc_insertion_point(includes)

namespace ddz {
namespace proto {

// Internal implementation detail -- do not call these.
void  protobuf_AddDesc_hello_2eproto();
void protobuf_AssignDesc_hello_2eproto();
void protobuf_ShutdownFile_hello_2eproto();

class LoginMessage;

// ===================================================================

class LoginMessage : public ::google::protobuf::MessageLite {
 public:
  LoginMessage();
  virtual ~LoginMessage();

  LoginMessage(const LoginMessage& from);

  inline LoginMessage& operator=(const LoginMessage& from) {
    CopyFrom(from);
    return *this;
  }

  static const LoginMessage& default_instance();

  #ifdef GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER
  // Returns the internal default instance pointer. This function can
  // return NULL thus should not be used by the user. This is intended
  // for Protobuf internal code. Please use default_instance() declared
  // above instead.
  static inline const LoginMessage* internal_default_instance() {
    return default_instance_;
  }
  #endif

  void Swap(LoginMessage* other);

  // implements Message ----------------------------------------------

  LoginMessage* New() const;
  void CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(const ::google::protobuf::MessageLite& from);
  void CopyFrom(const LoginMessage& from);
  void MergeFrom(const LoginMessage& from);
  void Clear();
  bool IsInitialized() const;

  int ByteSize() const;
  bool MergePartialFromCodedStream(
      ::google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream* input);
  void SerializeWithCachedSizes(
      ::google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream* output) const;
  int GetCachedSize() const { return _cached_size_; }
  private:
  void SharedCtor();
  void SharedDtor();
  void SetCachedSize(int size) const;
  public:

  ::std::string GetTypeName() const;

  // nested types ----------------------------------------------------

  // accessors -------------------------------------------------------

  // optional string userAccount = 1;
  inline bool has_useraccount() const;
  inline void clear_useraccount();
  static const int kUserAccountFieldNumber = 1;
  inline const ::std::string& useraccount() const;
  inline void set_useraccount(const ::std::string& value);
  inline void set_useraccount(const char* value);
  inline void set_useraccount(const char* value, size_t size);
  inline ::std::string* mutable_useraccount();
  inline ::std::string* release_useraccount();
  inline void set_allocated_useraccount(::std::string* useraccount);

  // @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:ddz.proto.LoginMessage)
 private:
  inline void set_has_useraccount();
  inline void clear_has_useraccount();

  ::std::string* useraccount_;

  mutable int _cached_size_;
  ::google::protobuf::uint32 _has_bits_[(1 + 31) / 32];

  #ifdef GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER
  friend void  protobuf_AddDesc_hello_2eproto_impl();
  #else
  friend void  protobuf_AddDesc_hello_2eproto();
  #endif
  friend void protobuf_AssignDesc_hello_2eproto();
  friend void protobuf_ShutdownFile_hello_2eproto();

  void InitAsDefaultInstance();
  static LoginMessage* default_instance_;
};
// ===================================================================


// ===================================================================

// LoginMessage

// optional string userAccount = 1;
inline bool LoginMessage::has_useraccount() const {
  return (_has_bits_[0] & 0x00000001u) != 0;
}
inline void LoginMessage::set_has_useraccount() {
  _has_bits_[0] |= 0x00000001u;
}
inline void LoginMessage::clear_has_useraccount() {
  _has_bits_[0] &= ~0x00000001u;
}
inline void LoginMessage::clear_useraccount() {
  if (useraccount_ != &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
    useraccount_->clear();
  }
  clear_has_useraccount();
}
inline const ::std::string& LoginMessage::useraccount() const {
  return *useraccount_;
}
inline void LoginMessage::set_useraccount(const ::std::string& value) {
  set_has_useraccount();
  if (useraccount_ == &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
    useraccount_ = new ::std::string;
  }
  useraccount_->assign(value);
}
inline void LoginMessage::set_useraccount(const char* value) {
  set_has_useraccount();
  if (useraccount_ == &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
    useraccount_ = new ::std::string;
  }
  useraccount_->assign(value);
}
inline void LoginMessage::set_useraccount(const char* value, size_t size) {
  set_has_useraccount();
  if (useraccount_ == &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
    useraccount_ = new ::std::string;
  }
  useraccount_->assign(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(value), size);
}
inline ::std::string* LoginMessage::mutable_useraccount() {
  set_has_useraccount();
  if (useraccount_ == &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
    useraccount_ = new ::std::string;
  }
  return useraccount_;
}
inline ::std::string* LoginMessage::release_useraccount() {
  clear_has_useraccount();
  if (useraccount_ == &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
    return NULL;
  } else {
    ::std::string* temp = useraccount_;
    useraccount_ = const_cast< ::std::string*>(&::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString);
    return temp;
  }
}
inline void LoginMessage::set_allocated_useraccount(::std::string* useraccount) {
  if (useraccount_ != &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
    delete useraccount_;
  }
  if (useraccount) {
    set_has_useraccount();
    useraccount_ = useraccount;
  } else {
    clear_has_useraccount();
    useraccount_ = const_cast< ::std::string*>(&::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString);
  }
}


// @@protoc_insertion_point(namespace_scope)

}  // namespace proto
}  // namespace ddz

// @@protoc_insertion_point(global_scope)

#endif  // PROTOBUF_hello_2eproto__INCLUDED
```

Comment: `please show me the detail code`?? What does it mean?

Comment: I mean that if the problem can be solved, I hope that someone can paste the c++ code or step, my english is just so so(shy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method, SerializeToArray is defined as "bool SerializeToArray(void* data, int size) const;" within the message_lite.h file.

I can see that #include  has been defined in your 'hello.proto' file. So you should have access to this function within your calling program.

See the example at proto file and call to Serialize method at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945901/3685825

In past, I have pushed the serialized data across the socket. You may need to consider adding message Length before the actual message and send it across socket.

See the example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339251/3685825

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Patel, I solved the problem by your answer, I use Xcode, but protobuf environment is not aviable, just for design code, so "SerializeToArray" method is missing, then I compile c++ code by NDK, successfully sent the message to server! Thank you very much----from a Chinese.